# Prove that $d$ is a gcd of $a_1, ..., a_n$ iff $\langle d\rangle = \langle a_1\rangle + \cdots + \langle a_n\rangle$.

Tags: ring-theory

**To anyone encountering this problem:** As the comments and answer correctly point out, if $R$ is a commutative ring with identity, and $\langle d\rangle = \langle a_1\rangle + \cdots + \langle a_n\rangle$, then $d$ is a gcd of $a_1, ..., a_n$. If, additionally, $R$ is *Noetherian* (for instance if $R$ is a PID), then this becomes an *equivalence*. However, if $R$ is not Noetherian this may fail (as in the example given by Exodd).

Furthermore, in any commutative ring $R$ with identity, the following *stronger* statement is true: $d\in R$ is a gcd of $a_1, ..., a_n$ *and* is equal to $r_1 a_1 + \cdots + r_n a_n$ for some $r_i\in R$ **iff** $\langle d\rangle = \langle a_1 \rangle + \cdots + \langle a_n\rangle$.

---

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, and let $a_1, ..., a_n\in R$. I would like to prove that $d\in R$ is a gcd of $a_1, ..., a_n$ iff $\langle d\rangle = \langle a_1\rangle + \cdots + \langle a_n\rangle$.

If $\langle d\rangle = \langle a_1\rangle + \cdots + \langle a_n\rangle$, then $\langle a_i\rangle \subseteq\langle d\rangle$, so $d\mid a_i$ for all $i$. Furthermore, if $c\mid a_i$ for all $i$, then $\langle a_i\rangle\subseteq\langle c\rangle$, so $\langle a_1 \rangle + \cdots + \langle a_n\rangle\subseteq\langle c\rangle$, or $\langle d\rangle\subseteq\langle c\rangle$, so $c\mid d$, implying $d$ is a gcd of $a_1, ..., a_n$.

I'm finding the other direction trickier. I thought I had an argument but I can't quite make it work. First, if $d \mid a_i$ then $\langle a_i\rangle \subseteq\langle d\rangle$ for all $i$, so $\langle a_1\rangle + \cdots +\langle a_n\rangle \subseteq \langle d\rangle$.

My idea was this: let $J = \{I\subseteq \langle a_1\rangle + \cdots + \langle a_n\rangle\ |\ I\ \text{principal ideal}\}$, ordered by inclusion. $\color{red}{\text{Then $J$ has a maximal element by Zorn's lemma.}}$ This is not actually true, as only *finite* chains have upper bounds in $J$, unless $R$ is a PID. That is, if we have an arbitrary collection of principal ideals $\{\langle a\rangle\}_{a\in A}$, totally ordered by inclusion, then we cannot guarantee that $\bigcup_{a\in A}\langle a\rangle$ is also a **principal** ideal (it is an ideal however).

If we roll with it, letting $\langle d\rangle$ be a maximal element of $J$, clearly as $\langle a_i\rangle\subseteq \langle a_1\rangle + \cdots + \langle a_n\rangle$ we must have $\langle a_i\rangle\subseteq\langle d\rangle$, so $d \mid a_i$. Furthermore, if $c \mid a_i$, then $\langle a_1\rangle + \cdots + \langle a_n\rangle \subseteq\langle c\rangle$, so $\langle d\rangle\subseteq\langle c\rangle$, and thus $c \mid d$. So $d$ is a gcd of $a_1, ..., a_n$.

Can I modify my argument to make this work? Is there a simpler route I've missed?

Comment: I think you need a PID to make it work.

Comment: @Wuestenfux I was wondering that myself, but I haven't looked for a counterexample yet. I'll check the book (Hungerford's "Algebra") to see if I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: If $R$ is Noetherian, then every set of ideals has a maximal element. Hence constructing a counterexample would need a non-Noetherian ring.

Comment: @Crostful You're right, it seems my argument works in a Noetherian setting.

Comment: Take $a_1=x_1$ ,$a_2 = x_2$ in $\mathbb K[x_1,x_2]$. The only gcd  is 1

Comment: @Exodd Thank you! If one of you wants to type that up as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_1 = x_1$ and $a_2 = x_2$ in $\mathbb K[x_1,x_2]$, for any field $\mathbb K$.
The only gcd of $a_1,a_2$ are the elements of $\mathbb K^*$, but
$$
<1> = \mathbb K[x_1,x_2] \ne <x_1,x_2> = <x_1> + <x_2>
$$